# i am making website but when i insert image my text gets disturbed

Tags: javascript, html, css

Theres a lot of space between welocme crafty and body text

[A lot of space between Title and bod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2MHl.png)

Comment: It is impossible for us to troubleshoot that from a screenshot without you providing the relevant code that produces it. See [ask] and  [mre]

Answer (score 0):

-- You have to spacify the container size.
-- using "display:flex" you can easly adjust layout.
(https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp)

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        .main-hero {
            padding: 100px 0;
        }

        .main-hero .container {
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .main-hero .container .text-content {
            width: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding: 0 20px;
            margin-right: 100px;
        }

        .main-hero .container .image-wrapper {
            width: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }

        .main-hero .container .image-wrapper img {
            width: 100%;
            vertical-align: revert;
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="main-hero">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text-content">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>

            <!-- /Image from unsplash.com / -->
            <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643779374814-3abaf4546e30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</body>
</html>
```